# Incorrect result from a multiplication of Integer

Tags: matlab, uint

I read a DICOM image and I extracted some of its characteristics such as width and height.
Now I want to save in a variable the number of total pixels of the image.
This is the code:

```
info = dicominfo(filename);

width = info.Width;
height = info.Height;
colorType = info.ColorType;
format = info.Format;
size = info.FileSize;
numberOfPixels = width*height;
k = info.BitDepth;
```

And these are the prints:

```
  Size: 256 x 256
  Color type: grayscale
  Format: DICOM
  Size: 137024 bytes
  NumberOfPixels: 65535
```

The `numberOfPixels` value is wrong. Why?

I thought it was a cast problem and so I also tried adding `uint32(width*height)` but nothing, I get 65535 instead of 65536.
Why?

Thank you

Comment: What's the type of `width` and `height`? 256*256 just gives 65536..... By the way you should cast before multiplying e.g. `uint32(width)*uint32(height)`

Comment: Thank you! It was an easy mistake to be solved, I feel a little stupid, thank you so much!

Comment: an important note: do not give names to variables that are also names of matlab functions. It can cause many problems, sometimes even without knowing that. Here you have `height`,`width`,`format`,`size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast *before* multiplying e.g. `uint32(width)*uint32(height)`.